# Did I correctly prove this?(Group theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let the $G$ is a group $s.t.$ its order is $150$

And Uniquely exists subgroup of the $G$ $s.t.$ its order is $6$

Show the existence of the subgroup whose order is $30$

---

When I solve this question, I don't have a confidence that my solution is right or not. Any advice or comments would be appreciated.

My attempt) $150 = 2\cdot 3 \cdot 5^2$

By the sylow thm, There are sylow 2, 3 subgroups in $G$ respectively.

Let the Sylow 2 group $P_2$ and sylow 3 group $P_3$

Since $H = P_2  \times P_3 $ and $H$ is a unique, Hence Each $P_2$ and $P_3$ are  unique. (I.e. $P_2 \unlhd G, P_3 \unlhd G$)

Hence $H \unlhd G $ $s.t.  \vert H \vert  = 6$

Plus there are the other sylow 5 subgroup $P_5$ $s.t.\vert P_5 \vert = 25$

Surely By cauchy thm, $\exists g \in P_5$ $ s.t.$ $\vert g \vert = 5$

So, $\langle g \rangle \leq P_5$ and $\vert \langle g \rangle  \vert = 5 $

Therefore $\langle g \rangle$$H$ is a subgroup of the $G$, and its order is $30$.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) $H$ is unique subgroup of order $6$, so it is normal.

(2) There exists subgroup $\langle g\rangle$ of order $5$. So product $\langle g\rangle H$ is subgroup, and its order is $30$.

The argument's of Sylow $2$,$3$-subgroups is unnecessary. Even instead of Sylow-$5$ subgroup, we need subgroup of order $5$ only; so modulo "Sylow" the rest of arguments give the proof.